# Find Values in cell array of struct

Tags: matlab, struct, cell

I have two cell array's with structure in it.

example:

```
xmlFB = 
Columns 1 through 5
[1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]
```

xmllink = 
Columns 1 through 3
[1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]

xmlFB{1}
ans =

`Param: {[1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]}
InterChartConnection: [1x1 struct]
               Tasks: [1x1 struct]
          Attributes: [1x1 struct]


xmllink{1}
ans = 
          Attributes: [1x1 struct]`

In "**xmllink**" there is the struct "**Attributes**" and in there is the Field "**Name**" with the Value "**EN1**"

And in xmlFB in the struct "**Attributes**" there are two Fields "**Name**" and "**Typ**"

The Names are unique.

What i want to do is to find the "**Typ**" in "**xmlFB**" from the names in the "**xmllink**".

First i wanted to do with a Loop, but the i read about these arrayfun/structfun/cellfun functions from Matlab.

Is there a way to do this with these? Or is a Loop better?

Comment: Please specify exactly what are the class and size of values in Name and Typ fields.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you right. But they are both char and max. is 20 characters.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what's needed. I basically asked for output of `class` and `size` functions. Just to make sure my assumption was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that all variables in Names and Typ are strings. (Should work for scalars as well.)

Here is how to get the values into cell arrays and link them.

```
% create cell arrays
xmllinkname = cellfun(@(x) x.Attributes.Name, xmllink, 'UniformOutput',0);
xmlFBname = cellfun(@(x) x.Attributes.Name, xmlFB, 'UniformOutput',0);
xmlFBtyp = cellfun(@(x) x.Attributes.Typ, xmlFB, 'UniformOutput',0);

% match names
[idx1, idx2] = ismember(xmllinkname,xmlFBname);
idx2(idx2==0)=[]; % in case some names in xmllink absent in xmlFB

% get matched names and typ
xmllinknamematched = xmllinkname(idx1);
xmllinktyp = xmlFBtyp(idx2);
```

Since the order of values in the first cell arrays will be the same as in your original cell arrays of structures, you can use those indices `idx1` and `idx2` to match the structures as well.

```
xmllinkmatched = xmllink(idx1);
xmlFBmatched = xmlFB(idx2);
```

Of course, you can avoid creating the temporary arrays and put the first two `cellfun` statement into `ismember` statement.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis You have been away for too long, Rody :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the loop.

First things first: only start worrying about performance when it is actually a problem, and only ***after*** you get it right.

Now, if I understood you correctly, here are generally two ways to accomplish what you want:

```
% create some bogus data with the same structure
% ---------------------------

f_xmllink = @(N) struct(...
    'Attributes', struct(...
        'Name', num2str(N))...
);

f_xmlFB = @(N) struct(...
    'Attributes', struct(...
        'Name', num2str(N),...
        'Typ' , num2str(N))...
);

% using numbers as names
xmllink = {
    f_xmllink(190)
    f_xmllink(331) % 2
    f_xmllink(321) % 3
    f_xmllink(239) 
};

xmlFB = {
    f_xmlFB(331) % 1
    f_xmlFB(200)
    f_xmlFB(108)
    f_xmlFB(321) % 4
    f_xmlFB(035)
};


% Example of a no-loop approach
% ---------------------------

tic

s_exp   = @(s, field) [s.(field)];
s_exp_C = @(s, field) {s.(field)};

one = s_exp_C(s_exp( [xmllink{:}], 'Attributes'), 'Name');
two = s_exp_C(s_exp( [xmlFB{:}], 'Attributes'), 'Name');

[i,j] = find(strcmp(repmat(one,numel(two),1), repmat(two,numel(one),1).'));

s_exp_C(s_exp([xmlFB{i}], 'Attributes'), 'Typ')

toc

% Example of a loop approach
% ---------------------------

tic

for ii = 1:numel(xmllink)

    S = [xmlFB{:}];
    S = [S.Attributes];
    S = {S.Name};

    ind = strmatch(xmllink{ii}.Attributes.Name, S);
    if ~isempty(ind)
        xmlFB{ind}.Attributes.Typ
    end

end

toc
```

Output:

```
% no-loop 
ans = 
    '331'    '321'  % correct findings

Elapsed time is 0.001103 seconds.   

% loop
ans =
   331      % correct findings
ans =
   321

Elapsed time is 0.000666 seconds. % FASTER!
```

Granted, it's not a fair test to compare the performance, but I think everyone will agree that the looped version will at the very least not be *slower* than the non-loop version.

More importantly, speed isn't everything -- how long did it take you to understand the no-loop solution? Chances are you understood the loop solution in one read, whereas the no-loop solution is a lot more complicated and will have to be thoroughly documented and tested etc. Also, changes to the no-loop solution will be harder to implement than changes in the loop solution.

That advice to not use loops in Matlab is completely outdated; please ignore it :)